# Order of left/right coset of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

If we have a subgroup $H$ of group $G$ and let $a \in G$, then I think the order of left coset $aH$ is equal to that of $H$. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you can actually prove that by a bijection $ah \mapsto a^{-1}ah=h$ (since we are in a group).

Answer (score 1):

Proof: We know that $H<G$, then for any $a\in G$ we have to show that $|aH|=|H|$. There are two cases:

Case I: $a\in H$. In this case $aH=H$ which implies that $|aH|=|H|$ .

Case II:$a\notin H$. Let $|H|=n$ then we know that $aH=\{ab_1, ab_2,ab_3,....ab_n\}$. Clearly, the order of $aH$ cannot exceed $n$ and since all elements are unique $ab_i\neq ab_j$, for any $1\leq i,j\leq n$. So order of $aH$ is equal to order of $H$.